# How can I eliminate a book's connection made with Workbook.caller()

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, xlwings

I have a python script for open a workbook. I need use this script many times but I receive a message error like this:

> C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings_xlwindows.py:159: UserWarning: This Work book is open in multiple instances.The connection was made with the one that was last active. warn('This Workbook is open in multiple instances.'

I need to avoid it. I don't know if I can unmade the book's connection or use another method for open the workbook.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're just seeing a bug that sneaked in with Excel >= 2013 since that is when they started to open a new window for each workbook even if you're working with just a single instance of Excel. See [here](https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/454).
This warning should only appear if you have the very same workbook opened in two different instances of Excel so until it is fixed, you can safely ignore the message.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it's the very same problem. In fact, I can ignore the message but I don't know if I can avoid the error message with any configuration (in xlwings or Excel). Your project is so cool ! Thank you again.

Comment: No, you need to wait for the bug fix.